# Reading and Writing with char* to file

Tags: c++

I am wondering how can you write  data of type char*,int,double using char* and also reading a whole file line by line using again char* ? I know it can be done with std:string really beautiful but I am interested with char*. I have created a Write() method which writes char* successfully
but I don't know how to adjust it for ints and doubles, also I have started creating Read() method to read each line and save it to char* then print it to the console but I don't know how to implement it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void Write(char* fileName, char* pData)
{

    ofstream file (fileName, ios::out | ios::app );
    if (file.is_open())
    {
     size_t len = strlen(pData);
    file.write(pData, len);

    }
}


void Read(char* fileName, char* pData)
{
    ifstream file(fileName, ios::in );
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file.read((char*)&pData, sizeof(pData));
        file.close();
    }
}



int main()
{

    char* fileName = "E:\\cpp\\CarsIO\\data.txt";
    char* data = "hello\n";
    Write(fileName , data);

    char* read = "";
    Read(fileName , read);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(pData)` will give you the size of a pointer, *not* the original sizeof the array: Arrays decay to pointers automatically in most situations, including passing them as a function parameter. If you want to get correct size you need to fetch it *before* the array decayed, i. e. as long as you have access to the original declaration – you'd then pass the size as *additional* parameter to the function(s) in question.

Comment: `char* read = "";` is not legal in C++, string literals are of type `char const*`. The assignment is accepted by some compilers for legacy reasons, but you should get a warning emitted. *Writing* to string literals is *undefined behaviour*. If you want to have a read buffer available, you need to define an array with appropriate size: `char buffer[256];`. Size is just an example, chose whatever appears appropriate to you.

Comment: Fixing the above, you're plagued with another problem. `file.read((char*)&pData, sizeof(pData));`, overwrites the value of the local `pData` (i.e. the value of the pointer, not what it actually points to). In this case that saving grace is ironically the only thing keeping this from invoking undefined behavior, as `pData` initial refers to read-only data (an empty literal) and the resulting blast over the original pointer value is never subsequently dereferenced.

Comment: For other types than C strings you need to decide if you want to store them in binary or textual (human readable) representation. Outputting in textual representation is done pretty easily with `operator>>`. However reading back is more critical. You need to be able to detect the borders of strings and numbers when reading; consider your strings containing digits or whitespace. You might need to add additional information on writing to be able to split correctly when reading back.

Comment: Don't forget that I/O can fail at any moment, even after opening the file. Also, even if you check the state of a file, like with `if (file.isopen())`, consider adding an `else`-branch that returns an error some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a Write() method which writes char* successfully but I don't know how to adjust it for ints and doubles [...]

First of all, the function [`std::ofstream::write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) is intended for unformatted (binary) I/O. Since you are outputting text, it would be easier to use the formatted I/O functions, for example [`operator <<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), like this:

```
void Write( char* fileName, char* pData )
{
    ofstream file( fileName, ios::out | ios::app );
    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        file << pData;
    }
    if ( !file )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}
```

In order for the function `Write` to print data of type `int`, you can simply create an appropriate [overloaded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/) function `Write`, like this:

```
void Write( char* fileName, int data )
{
    ofstream file( fileName, ios::out | ios::app );
    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        file << data;
    }
    if ( !file )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}
```

In order to make it also print the data type `double`, you can create an additional overloaded function for this data type. You can simply copy the function above and change `int data` to `double data`.

However, now you have 3 overloaded functions, one for the data type `char *`, one for `int` and one for `double`. That is a lot of unnecessary code duplication. It would be less messy to make a single template function, which can handle all three data types:

```
template <typename T>
void Write( char* fileName, T data )
{
    ofstream file( fileName, ios::out | ios::app );
    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        file << data;
    }
    if ( !file )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}
```

---

> [...] also I have started creating Read() method to read each line and save it to char* then print it to the console but I don't know how to implement it.

The function [`std::ifstream::read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) is intended for unformatted (binary) input, not for formatted text input. Since you insist on using `char*` instead of `std::string`, I recommend that you use the function [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) in order to read exactly one line of text input, like this:

```
void Read( char* fileName, char* pData, std::streamsize count )
{
    ifstream file(fileName, ios::in );
    if(file.is_open())
    {
        file.getline( pData, count );
    }
    if ( !file )
    {
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}
```

In your code, you were simply using `sizeof(pData)` to pass the size of the memory buffer. This will not work, because this will give you the size of the pointer `pData` (which is probably 4 or 8 bytes), instead of the size of the memory buffer. That is why the function `Read` must take an additional parameter which specifies the size of the memory buffer.

In your code, you are calling the function `Read` like this:

```
char* read = "";
Read(fileName , read);
```

This code is wrong, for two reasons:

1. You must ensure that the memory buffer is large enough to store the read data. This would be handled automatically when using `std::string`, but you must handle this yourself when using `char*`.
2. The line `char* read = "";` makes the pointer `read` point to an (empty) string literal. String literals are read only. That is why C++ requires that pointers to string literals are declared as `const char *` instead of `char *`. You cannot pass a pointer to a read-only string literal to the function `Read`, because that function will attempt to write to that string literal, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In order to call the function `Read` and print the result, you can use the following code:

```
char buffer[100];

Read( fileName, buffer, sizeof buffer );

std::cout << buffer << "\n";
```